Non-regular Misiurewicz quadratic maps necessarily satisfy the Collet-Eckmann condition?
I am working through a paper and it seems to me that the authors assume that a quadratic map $f_a(x) = 1-ax^2$ that satisfies the Misiurewicz condition ( $\inf_{n > 0} |f_a^n(0)| > 0$ ) and doesn't have periodic attractors necessarily satisfies the Collet-Eckmann condition:
\begin{equation} \liminf \sqrt[n]{|\left(f^n\right)'(f(0))|} > 1.\quad\quad\quad\quad (1) \end{equation}
I was unable to show this and can't find such a result anywhere. Can someone please provide an explanation or a reference to one?
P.S. It seems like they think the absence of a periodic attractor isn't relevant here, only the Misiurewicz condition.
